# Is there a way to shut off the comic relief voices in Oddworld: New 'n' Tasty?

Tags: oddworld-new-n-tasty

I'm playing *Oddworld: New 'n' Tasty* on Steam. It's taken some liberties over the original game, some good and some not so much. There's one that's grating for me: the Sligs and Mudokons all have some idle comic relief commentary, and they'll mutter it constantly, stuff like:

> **Slig:** Ugh, when's lunch?
>   **Slig:** Maybe I'll even get paid this month.
>   **Mudokon:** Another day in the office...
>   **Mudokon:** Employee of the month! Now I even have my own brush!

In the original, everyone was silent and there was a really oppressive atmosphere to Rupture Farms. Suffice to say this commentary is *really* atmosphere-breaking for me and is making it hard to fully enjoy the game.

Is there a way to shut off the commentary, and only the commentary?

The volume control for voices also controls gamespeak and cues like a Slig saying "what!?", and subtitles don't display these messages, so that in itself doesn't solve much.

Comment: If you can find out which files in the game folder hold these sounds you could try to replace them with empty sound files that just play nothing or one second of silence when the game tries to play them.